# Can I call an individual element of an array stored in Parse using index value.

Tags: android, sql, arrays, parse-platform

I want to alter a value at a specific index number in an array column in parse using android. Currently I have to get the entire array, store it in a local integer array, alter the value in the required index number and put the local array back to the table. Is there an easier way to just retrieve the value (as well as put it back) and not the entire array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your array is an array of integers, then you will need to retrieve the full parent object, modify the array property and save the parent object. You'll have to hope/trust that Parse will do just what is needed.

Your unspoken questions is if there is any kind of "patch" function, to which the answer is currently no.

If instead you have an array of parse objects, you can make changes to the object directly as the array only stores pointers. Add/remove will still require manipulation of the array on the parent object though (and subsequent save of the parent object), same as for an array of integers.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know the `objectId`, retrieving the entire array is the only way to do that. When you "put it back" or save it, you do not need to save the entire array, but only the `parseObject` you altered. Hope this helps. Let me know if you need more help.